# height:100% and window resize: height won't longer be 100%

Tags: css, height

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You get container to use all height, but if you resize the window to 50% for example and reload the page, and once is loaded you resize the window to use the whole size the extra space is not used by `#container` (in this case will be using 50% of the total window size).

What's the best way to fix this and if posible using only css?

Comment: Use `position: absolute;` instead of the float. Can't think of anything else if we got no source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to work :

http://jsfiddle.net/AhFnS/

Maybe you have an element containing your `#container`